# Invalid syntax on if-else statement

Tags: python, syntax-error

Can someone explain why I am getting an invalid syntax error from Python's interpreter while formulating this simple `if/else` statement? I don't add any tabs myself I simply type the text then press enter after typing. When I type an enter after "else:" I get the error. `else` is highlighted by the interpreter. What's wrong?

```
>>> if 3 > 0:
        print("3 greater than 0")
        else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try removing the indents before `else:`

Comment: The else has to be indented the same amount as the if.

Comment: @PinnyM Thank you, that fixed it. I had trouble figuring out how to remove the indent in interactive mode. When writing code in the Python shell, you have to press backspace after you press [enter] but BEFORE you write the "else:" statement; you can't use shift+[tab] to fix the indent like you can in other editors.

Comment: ```if``` can have another indented ```if```. ```else``` needs a parent ```if```.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python does not allow empty blocks, unlike many other languages (since it doesn't use braces to indicate a block). The `pass` keyword must be used any time you want to have an empty block (including in if/else statements and methods).

For example,

```
if 3 > 0:
    print('3 greater then 0')
else:
    pass
```

Or an empty method:

```
def doNothing():
    pass
```

Comment: Please note (for future visitors) that this isn't always an indentation error. I had it once where I forgot a ")" the line before.

Answer (score 8):

That's because your `else` part is empty and also not properly indented with the `if`.

```
if 3 > 0:
    print "voila"
else:    
    pass
```

In python `pass` is equivalent to `{}` used in other languages like C.

Answer (score 4):

The `else` block needs to be at the same indent level as the `if`:

```
if 3 > 0:
    print('3 greater then 0')
else:
    print('3 less than or equal to 0')
```

Answer (score 4):

The keyword `else` has to be indented with respect to the `if` statement respectively

**e.g.**

```
a = 2
if a == 2:
    print "a=%d", % a
else:
    print "mismatched"
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Click to open image]

The problem is indent only.

You are using IDLE. When you press enter after first print statement indent of else is same as print by default, which is not OK. You need to go to start of else sentence and press back once. Check in attached image what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

it is a  obvious mistake we do, when we press enter after the if statement it will come into that intendation,try by keeping the else statement as straight with the if statement.it is a common typographical error

Comment: I found this comment useful because it gives me an idea of what Python programmers usually deal with.

Comment: I think this comment was helpful because it shows that people who commonly program in Python run into this simple indentation problem. I want to point out that in the interactive editor, unlike most other IDEs and text processors, you have to press [Enter] after the statements following the if statement to get to the line where you want to put in "else:", then you have to hit the [Backspace] key to go to the same indention as the "if" statement, then you type "else:". In other editors you would be able to type "else:" then [Shift]+[Tab] to fix the indentation.

Answer (score -1):

Else needs to be vertically aligned. Identation is playing a key role in Python. I was getting the same syntax error while using else. Make sure you indent your code properly

Comment: I think this simple question is already well answered, so why not skip this one?