# I'm having issues getting If_Elif to work on my Python Code

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and i'm not succeeding on making this procedure run properly. Can anyone please help?
The If and Elif pose Invalid Syntax,
What should I do?

I am using Python3.7.2 Shell IDLE

**1. convert temperature Fahrenheit to Celsius and Celsius to Fahrenheit**

```
temp = input("Input the  temperature you like to convert? (e.g.,45F, 102C etc.) : ")

degree = int(temp[:-1])
i_convention = temp[-1]

if i_convention.upper() == "C":
  result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5+32))
  o_convention = "Fahrenheit"
  print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

elif i_convention.upper() =="F":
  result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
  o_convention ="Celsius"
  print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

else:
  #Nul

print("Pas de resultat valide")
```

Comment: Maybe `python` tag should be here, not `c#`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual error message. I would guess that it's because the `else` block contains nothing but a comment. See [Invalid syntax on VERY SIMPLE Python if … else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14327195/2745495).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pass` to create an empty block in python.

**Edit**: Just realized that the final print statement is supposed to be an error message, so if you just fix the formatting of the last part, I think it works.

```py
temp = input("Input the  temperature you like to convert? (e.g.,45F, 102C etc.) : ")

degree = int(temp[:-1])
i_convention = temp[-1]

if i_convention.upper() == "C":
  result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5+32))
  o_convention = "Fahrenheit"
  print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

elif i_convention.upper() =="F":
  result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
  o_convention ="Celsius"
  print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

else:
  print("Pas de resultat valide")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place something in the `else:` block for the Python interpreter to run correctly.

I would recommend passing some error handling to the `else:` block, in the event that the input you get from the user is not valid for your script. Otherwise, try refactoring your code to look like this:

```
temp = input("Input the  temperature you like to convert? (e.g.,45F, 102C etc.) : ")

degree = int(temp[:-1])
i_convention = temp[-1]

if i_convention.upper() == "C":
    result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5+32))
    o_convention = "Fahrenheit"
    print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

else:
    result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
    o_convention ="Celsius"
    print("The temperature in", o_convention, "is", result, "degrees.")

print("Pas de resultat valide")
```

I would recommend wrapping the input statement into a while loop to verify user input.

```
temp = None
while temp[-1].upper() != "C" && temp[-1].upper() != "F"
    temp = temp = input("Input the  temperature you like to convert? (e.g.,45F, 102C etc.) : ")

# Put if, else statements below
```