# Calculate BMI with multiple options using (if, else)

Tags: python

**Description**:  I want to write a program that calculates the user's BMI using the following formula.

```
BMI= WeightInKilograms/HeightInMeters*HeightInMeters
```

*NOTE*: our height and weight inputs should be up to two digits after the decimal point, then show us the following messages according to the BMI range.

```
Underweight: BMI < 18.5
Normal: 18.5 <= BMI < 25
Overweight: 25 <= BMI < 30
Obese: 30 <= BMI
```

**Example**

```
input:
93
1.71

output:
31.80
Obese
```

**Problem**

When I run the code, it gives me an error related to the else logic. which part is wrong?

```
Weight_In_Kilograms = float(input())

Height_In_Meters = float(input())

BMI = Weight_In_Kilograms / Height_In_Meters*Height_In_Meters

print('BMI')

if 'BMI' < 18.5:
   print("Underweight")
   else 18.5 <= 'BMI'< 25:
   
   print("Normal")
   
   else 25 <= 'BMI' < 30:
        
       print("Overweight")
       
       else 30 <= 'BMI':
          print("Obese")
```

Comment: You should use the same [indentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) for each part of `if`. Also, check the syntax of `if` statement, here you can find that your `else` branch is not syntactically correct (if you need to check another condition, use `elif`). And finally, you compare string `'BMI'` with number, so you will never have what you expect.

Comment: So I can recommend you to check [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) and choose the most suitable tutorial to learn the basics with code explanation and excercises.

Comment: Why did you approve the duplicate and then posted the question to review for reopening?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I wanted to edit my question and ask for review so I could ask new questions.  This question has been answered before  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327195/invalid-syntax-on-very-simple-python-if-else-statement) and I can't delete my question.

Comment: @jasmine You can edit without adding to reopen review. You checked the checkbox saying that your edit should get the question reopened, which is contradictory if you had already agreed to closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there were several mistakes in your code as jaychandra mentioned. This is my solution to it.

(round(BMI, 2) simply means the program will round off your value to 2 decimal places (as in your example, where it would print 31.80)

```
Weight_In_Kilograms = float(input())

Height_In_Meters = float(input())

BMI = Weight_In_Kilograms / (Height_In_Meters**2)

print(round(BMI, 2))

if BMI < 18.5:
   print("Underweight")
elif 18 <= BMI < 25:
   print("Normal")
elif 25 <= BMI < 30:
    print("Overweight")
else:
    print("Obese")
```

Comment: thank you but why do we use this ? 
    print(round(BMI, 2))   in the top code isn't and works

Comment: change ```Height``` to ```Height_IN_Meters```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code. You are using else conditions inside an if condition. This will raise an error. Also, you cannot use else along with some conditions.

If you want to check for conditions in a nested form, then you should use the `elif` instead of the `else` keyword.

Also, you are checking those values with the string `'BMI'` instead of the variable `BMI`

Here is the corrected code.

```
Weight_In_Kilograms = float(input())

Height_In_Meters = float(input())

BMI = Weight_In_Kilograms / (Height_In_Meters*Height_In_Meters)

print('BMI')

if BMI < 18.5:
   print("Underweight")
elif BMI < 25:
   print("Normal")
elif BMI < 30:
    print("Overweight")
else:
    print("Obese")
```